# parallel_tests cucumber feature fails only in CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, parallel-testing

I'm working in a legacy ROR application with more test coverage so it will take near 1:30 hr to execute all rspec_cucumber in our semaphore CI. so we have implemented [Parallel_test][1]

[1]: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests. Gem and many time some feature spec or scenario fails only in CI environment. When we re-run the same test case in local and semaphore SSH environment the same spec passed.

The most common error in the log for CI environment is `Capybara::ElementNotFound:` it's challenging to identify the root cause of the issue. Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running on CI without the parallel test gem, then let the CI platform do the parallelization.

Maybe this will help https://semaphoreci.com/docs/running-cucumber-scenarios-in-threads.html.

I'm pretty sure semaphore supports parallel testing with rspec.

Also try running locally the whole suite with parallel test and see if you get the same issues.

Finally on command line look at `cucumber --help`. There are a number of options you can use to do the following

- add more debug info to a run
- identify your slowest scenarios, (perhaps you could tag these and run them less often).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue with **Capybara** and `parallel_tests` I've found that the more simultaneous tests you run at the same time the more "weird" issues you start having in Circle CI. That said, even though the chips in Circle CI (at least in our containers) have 18 cores. I've limited the number of simultaneous test to only 4 using the `-n 4` flag.

Thus, in my Ci configuration I use: `bundle exec parallel_rspec ~/repo/spec -n 4`